# The property() method of function class right using

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Example in the documentation:

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  // these will be supplied by `create`
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

var ironMan = App.Person.create({
  firstName: "Tony",
  lastName:  "Stark"
});

ironMan.get('fullName') // "Tony Stark"
```

I can't understand why I must specify dependencies like `.property('firstName', 'lastName')` if I had indicated what needs to return: `return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName')` and the example above can work without it (just using property()).
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for caching.

From [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html):

> By default the function backing the computed property will only be
>   called once and the result will be cached. You can specify various
>   properties that your computed property is dependent on. This will
>   force the cached result to be recomputed if the dependencies are
>   modified.